# UIImageJPEGRepresentation and UIImagePNGRepresentation returns nil in iOS 13

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, ios13

In my app I'm using the image picker to select an image on an iPhone. After the image was selected, I do:

```
data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

On iOS 12.4.1 and below, everything works fine, if I pick either PNG or JPEG image.

On iOS 13, JPG works fine, but PNG does not.

If I pick a JPG:

```
data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0); // works
data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); // works
```

But if I pick a PNG:

```
data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0); // data is nil
data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); // data is nil
```

I looked at some other questions here and tried copying the image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then, when I do

```
data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0);
```

it's not nil, but I get an all-white image.

Does anyone have an idea for a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved in beta 13.1.