# UIImageJPEGRepresentation not working in iOS 13.2.3

Tags: objective-c, ios13, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I am using the following code to convert `UIImage` to `NSData`:

```
imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75);
```

The code is working fine with iOS 12.4, but when I try with it with iOS 13.2.3, it returns nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am using Objective-C and when I check the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624115-jpegdata it seems that the Objective-C counterpart is the same as my code , wouldn't there be any other alternatives?  Thank you

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/58048339/2152616 it says that the issue has been solved in 13.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIImageJPEGRepresentation and UIImagePNGRepresentation returns nil in iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012911/uiimagejpegrepresentation-and-uiimagepngrepresentation-returns-nil-in-ios-13)

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have already checked this answer and unfortunately, it is not working with iOS 13.2.3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thoroughly examining and researching, it turned out that UIImageJPEGRepresentation with 0.75 compression was causing a crash due to large image size. Changing 0.75 to 0.1 solved the problem.